# AWS CLI list-policies to find a policy with a specific name

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-iam

I am trying to locate a policy in AWS with a specific name via the aws cli. I tried get-policy first but it threw and error. Now I am trying list-policies and putting in a prefix. According to the documentation if I start and end the string with a forward slash it should search but it hasn't been working. I get an empty array back... any ideas?

> aws iam list-policies --scope Local --path-prefix /policyname.xyz/

Comment: What is the actual, full ARN of the policy you are trying to find? Also how did you try `get-policy` and what error exactly did you get?

Comment: In this case the `--path-prefix` is supposed to be something like `/service-role/` or `/`  not the actual policy name, The policy name is (surprisingly) not part of the path (see [Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_Policy.html) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an issue with AWS CLI V2.
The issue is still open on the github repository of the AWS SDK since 11 Jan.
You can check the detail here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/36

Complete list of issues:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues

Comment: Thanks! I will need to do some filtering after I get all of the policies back as a workaround for now.

Comment: I don't think this is really related to the AWS CLI per se, you get the same error if you use any of the SDKs like boto3. The implementation of ListPolicies API in the server side is the one returning that error, it's not the CLI.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--query` flag. For example, for exact search,

```
aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[?PolicyName==`policyname.xyz`]'
```

If you want more flexible search, you can refer to https://jmespath.org/specification.html for some functions for example 'to start with policynamexxx'

```
aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[?starts_with(PolicyName,`policynamexxx`)]'
```

Comment: Beware that the `--query` does the filtering client-side NOT server-side, so you still read ALL the policies from AWS server, then the cli will filter out the results that not match the `--query`